# Выравнивание текста по центру блока

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
DIV.type_text
{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
DIV.type_text SPAN
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bolder;
    bottom: 25%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 9px;
    background-color: #FB3939;
}
```

Как вы видите, буква **Д** выходит за пределы дива.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы ***в такой ситуации*** половина буквы **Р** выходило за пределы (слева) и половина буквы **Д** (справа) выходило за пределы. (т.е. было строго по центру).

Может не совсем удачно описал, но думаю вы меня поймете.

Comment: Как выглядит HTML? `<div class="type_text"><span>РЯ</span>Д</div>`?

Comment: @PeterOlson именно

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `transform translate`

```css
div.type_text
{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FB3939;
}
div.type_text span
{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 9px;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="type_text"><span>РЯД</span></div>
```

Comment: У меня не очень-то по центру выглядит. http://joxi.ru/82Q4D1Zsj3a98m

Comment: @VostokSisters, ты учитывай шрифт и размеры каждой буквы. Чтобы было полностью по центру, в шрифте у букв не должны быть пустые места

Comment: Вот ты и учитывай, я-то чего (:

Answer (score 1):

```css
div.type_text{
  width: 100px;
  height:20px;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:22px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:600;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
div.type_text span{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
div.type_text::after{
  content:"";
  width:18px;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="type_text"><span>РЯ</span>Д</div>
```

Ииии да, от шрифта тут овердофига зависит((

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к вашим классам такие свойства:

```
.type_text {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.type_text span {
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
```